Syntax error within the name of the table
I am getting a syntax error from the following query:
SELECT * FROM natural-engine-438716-p4.babynames.names_2014

How to resolve the table location containing a keyword. This is within BigQuery.
The error code is the following: Syntax error: Unexpected keyword NATURAL at [2:6]

If you use a banned character such as - in the name, you must wrap it in backticks , such as :  SELECT * FROM natural-engine-438716-p4.babynames.names_2014  <--- without the spaces, the comment formatting removes them, but try that and I will type up a full answer after you confirm that fixes it.  Note that is not '.

I typed up the start of an answer explaining this a bit, let me know if you have any questions, if it works, and if so if you could mark it as the accepted answer if that is the case, thanks!

Neither fix worked, unfortunately. Inputting natural--engine--438716--p4.babynames.names_2014 still gave a syntax error and natural_engine_438716_p4.babynames.names_2014 returned invalid project ID

Just checking back, but usually when there is a correct solution to a question, the person that asked the question clicks the accept button on the question if it helped them.  And optionally they can click upvote if they like, but I just ask you to consider accepting the answer if it helped you.  I plan to add more information to it at that time.  Have a good day.

When searching for a table, you need to be careful about which characters that are used when naming.  In the example you gave, you have this query :

SELECT * FROM natural-engine-438716-p4.babynames.names_2014

The dash character, among many others such as backslash, are used directly by MYSQL for commands, so when you try to use them inside of db and table names, they can throw erorrs like the one you have seen.
Some characters can be escaped or terminated by doubling up the character, and in other cases, you can do wrapping of the names in question to allow them to exist with the offending character.
You must use a backtick, this character ` found to the left of the 1 key usually on the keyboard.  Wrap the db.table like this :

SELECT * FROM 'natural-engine-438716-p4.babynames.names_2014`

This should allow you to select that table without an issue.

This worked, thanks!
